# Determine which controller/action is invoked in ExecuteCore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `BaseController` class that all my controllers inherit from. It has an overriden `ExecuteCore` method which does some initial setup that is needed for (almost) all the controllers and their actions.

```
    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        SetUpMethod1();
        SetUpMethod2();
        base.ExecuteCore();
    }

    protected virtual void SetUpMethod1()
    {
       //some initialization stuff
    }

    protected virtual void SetUpMethod2()
    {
       //some other initialization stuff
    }
```

In the case when some controller needs some different behaviour, it's easy to override the relevant method in the controller, and that works well. However, there are some actions from different controllers that would need somewhat different behaviour in the set-up methods.

I've come up with

```
    protected virtual void SetUpMethod1()
    {
        string controller = (string)ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]);
        string action = (string)ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);
        if (controller/account combination is in a list)
            //special setup
        else
            //regular setup
    }
```

I cannot shake the feeling that I'm doing something wrong. Is there a better / correct way to get this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have authorization in your system?

Comment: @alok_dida: yes, authorization is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new attribute

```
public sealed class SpecialSetUpAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

I have defined two controllers, in which, I have defined this attribute for one controller only and not for other. Please see below code.

BasicController

```
public class BasicController : BaseController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Basic/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

}
```

Special setup controller

```
[SpecialSetUp]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{

}
```

Both controller derived from the BaseController. Please see code for the BaseController.

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
        {
            protected override void ExecuteCore()
            {
                Type controllerType = this.ControllerContext.Controller.GetType();
                ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType);

// Edit start
                string actionName = Convert.ToString(this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);
            string controller = Convert.ToString(this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]);

// Edit end

                if (controllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(SpecialSetUpAttribute), true))
                {
                    //Do special setup
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do normal setup
                }
                base.ExecuteCore();
            }
        }
```

When you run application for BasicController, it will execute normal setup code. When you run application for HomeController,it will execute special setup code.
I have implemented this code for the controller level. You can do samething for action level also.

Comment: Nice, solution, but how can I get the action name?

Comment: @SWeko . I have updated my code for that. Please see BaseController code for it. (Edit end and start.)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a slightly different direction.

Instead of having if-statement, I would have 2 base classes: BaseForSetup1Controller, BaseForSetup2Contoller.

So,

```
public class UsingSetup1Controller : BaseForSetup1Controller {}
```

and

```
public class UsingSetup2Controller : BaseForSetup2Controller {}
```

A little bit further: I prefer to use filters instead of base class initialization. So, you might create several initialization filters (action filters that using OnActionExecuting method) and apply those on controllers as you need.

```
[Setup1Initialization]
public class UsingSetup1Controller { }

[Setup2Initialization]
public class UsingSetup2Controller { }
```

Comment: The ifs are taken just for some actions across some controllers. I do not want the whole controller to have different behaviour (I can override the methods then), I just want different behaviour for a specific action(s).

Comment: Again, you can apply a filter on action with specific behavior.

Comment: Separate base classes wont do the trick, since most controllers require both setups.